# Rails: Specifying the sort order in the select form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, html-select, form-helpers

I'm using the Rails `select()` form helper to generate a `<select>` structure. The following line works, but results in an unsorted list. How would I change the sort order to ascending alphabetical?

```
<%= select('category', 'name', Category.all.collect { |category| [ category.name ] }) %>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the Rails 3 way:

```
<%= select('category', 'id',
            Category.order('name ASC').all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }) %>
```

This will generate the HTML options for each category like following:

```
<option value="1">CategoryName</option>
```

Where the value is the Category id and not its name:

You will get the `params[:category_id]` instead of `params[:category]` which would be a string containing the category name. Then to find a Category in the DB, it's much better to use an id (because they are unique, not like names) and its faster!